# XML Schema to validate XML Schemas?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

Does anyone know if its possible to validate an XML schema with another XML schema? If so, is there a reference implementation out there? I would like to parse a Schema doc using JAXB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course. Most of the time you can just point your browser to the URL that serves as the namespace for the XML document. This also works with XML Schema: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

The [XSD](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd) is linked from there.

Comment: +1 The XML Schema schema will let you validate whether your schema file is XML Schema valid.

Answer (score 2):

Also check [XSOM](https://xsom.dev.java.net/). This is what JAXB RI uses to load and process XSDs.

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of the XML Schema Definition Language (XSD): 1.0 and 1.1. Version 1.0 was released in 2001 and version 1.1 was released in 2009.

The normative XSD schemas are:

- http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd
- http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd

You can test the validation of an XSD schema via the command line, e.g.:

```
$ xmllint -noout -schema XMLSchema.xsd myschema.xsd
```